# Call native C++ function from C#

Tags: c#, c++, native-code

I have C++ legacy code with functions in the form:

```
double func(double)
```

**I have this as a source file** -  it isnt in the form of a DLL although it could be turned into one if necessary

How can I call `func` in my C# code (maybe over managed C++)? I heard of Marshalling and `DllImport` but I did not find MSDN very helpful.

Comment: `but I did not find MSDN very helpful.` hard to believe, but you have another alternative. Google....

Comment: What problem do you have with it? MSDN should help with that.

Comment: Is there no other way than making a DLL from it? Can't I use it directly from C++/CLI?

Comment: 3 options I can think of (just look in google for more info):
1. Export functions from the C++ DLL and than p/invoke from C#.
2. Make C++ COM object and than reference it from C#
3. Use C++/CLI to make managed functions, than use conversion functions to change the parameters from managed to unmanaged and use them to call the unmanaged C++

Comment: Thanks fpr the tip using COM - I did'nt have that idea

Answer (score -2):

You have to compile C++ code as DLL library and then DllImport is way to go.

I don't know what problem you have with it. On MSDN I found this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5.aspx

And also this article: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/  seems to be quite useful.